# sqlite database OK but jdbc reports database disk image is malformed

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, groovy, malformed

I have a newly created sqlite database, it is somewhat large: about 6.3GB. I have no problems using it through the sqlite command line tool. When I try to connect using the JDBC (groovy script) I got the exception:

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image 

is malformed (database disk image is malformed)
```

I then ran from the sqlite command line tool:

`pragma integrity_check;`

which reported back with: `ok`

I tried out the groovy script against a new database with a single table with a single row and it appears to work.

Any suggestions?

using:

jdk1.7.0_60

groovy-2.3.4

sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2

groovy script:

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet


println("hello world")

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")

String dbFile =
        "/opt/no_backup/text_analytics/db/options.sqlite3"  //large database - exception
//        "/opt/no_backup/text_analytics/test/test.db"      //small database - works

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:$dbFile")

String query =
//        "select count(*) from test"                                   //small database - works
      "select count(*) from bb_options where underlyingSymbol='GE'"     //large database - fails

ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query)

while(rs.next()) {
    println(rs.getInt(1))
}

conn.close()
```

Comment: What `file` command gives on your db files?  `/opt/no_backup/text_analytics/db/options.sqlite3` `/opt/no_backup/text_analytics/test/test.db`

Comment: I think your best option is to export the data and import it into a new db file.